# Resizing Row/Column height/width of a Word Table from an spreadsheet range Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

The range of cells that I copy and paste into a word becomes a table. I want to know how to reference the word table and resize the row height and column width to fit a given size.

```
Sub RangeImporter()
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application

Dim rng As Range

Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
wrdApp.documents.Add
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set rng = Range("A27", Range("A27").End(xlDown))
rng.Copy

With wrdApp.Selection
    .Paste
End With


wrdApp.Quit

Set wrdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am very new to this and have very little background apart from what I have picked up here. Any help/tips/critiques  would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/word-vba/articles/rows-setheight-method-word?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm155975883)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) on the microsoft dev center site. 
I changed:

```
With wrdApp.Selection
.Paste
End With
```

To
*

```
With wrdApp.Selection
    .Paste
    .Tables(1).Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(0.2), HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly
End With
```

*
I'm sure I can apply this concept to columns, font size ect.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to reference the word table and resize the row height and column width to fit a given size.

```
Sub Table4SlowRandy()
    Dim aTbl As Word.Table

    ' paste a table from Excel
    Selection.Range.Paste

    ' Assign pasted table to variable
    Set aTbl = Selection.Range.Tables(1)

    ' Modify aTbl as you like
    aTbl.Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(0.2), HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly

    ' Deallocate aTbl
    Set aTbl = Nothing

End Sub
```